# How to run Post-Build Command Line on only 1 target?

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop, openfl, haxeflixel

After building, FlashDevelop will run this in Project > Properties > Build > Post-Build Command Line:

```
"$(ProjectDir)\debug-android.bat"
```

The bat file will install my game on my phone. It's supposed to run only on Android target. But it also runs on Flash target. So how to disable it on Flash target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the `TargetBuild` variable to your `.bat` file:

`$(ProjectDir)\debug-android.bat $(TargetBuild)`

Then simply exit early if the argument value is not `android`:

```
if not %1 == android goto :eof

echo Running on android
```

---

Check `Project -> Properties -> Build -> Builder...` for all available variables and their current value.

Comment: You can also create separate batch files for each target: `$(ProjectDir)\debug-$(TargetBuild).bat`

Comment: Nice idea! However, it doesn't really suit this particular use case too well.

Comment: @MarkKnol Actually, I only need the game installed on Android platform. The other platform is Flash which doesn't need to be installed on.

Comment: Nevermind. After a while, I learn how to add a line to check if the "%1" argument is null or blank. If it's true, it will skip your line.